# Extractall in python

Tags: python, zip

Im trying to extract files from zip file with a password this is my code

```
def extractFile(zfile,password):
    """
    tries to open a file 
    prints SUCCESS if the file opend 
    prints FAILED if the file failed to open
    """
    try:
        z=zipfile.ZipFile(zfile)
        t=z.namelist()
        z.extractall("D://",t,password)
        print ("Success the password is "+password)
        return True
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Fail! "+password+" is wrong!")
        return False
def attack(zFile,dFile):
    lines=dFile.readlines()
    i=0
    stop=len(lines)
    while(1):
        if i==stop:
            print "end of passwords"
            return False
        pas=lines[i]
        x=extractFile(zFile,pas.rstrip())
        if x==True:
            return True
        else:
            i=i+1
f=file("secret.zip")
f1=open("dict.txt","r")
total=attack(f,f1)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Whenever I try to extract the files I get alot of errors msgs

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Test\crack.py", line 40, in <module>
    total=attack(f,f1)
  File "D:\Test\crack.py", line 33, in attack
    x=extractFile(zFile,pas.rstrip())
  File "D:\Test\crack.py", line 18, in extractFile
    z.extractall("D://",t,password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1036, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1024, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1080, in _extract_member
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 49, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 628, in read
    data = self.read1(n - len(buf))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 680, in read1
    max(n - len_readbuffer, self.MIN_READ_SIZE)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

What is wrong? I've been stuck on my problem for like a hour and couldn't figure out where is the problem
Once It gets to the right passwords it just crashes and prints the errors I typed above

Comment: You're going way out of your way to make things harder for yourself, and for everyone who reads and tries to debug your code for you. For example, more than half of `attack` is a complicated way of writing `for pas in dFile:`.

Comment: Meanwhile, what makes you think it's gotten to the right password?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to crack a zip from a list of passwords contained in a file:

```
import zipfile
def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        return password
    except:
        return
def attack():
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('yourarchive.zip')
    with open('dictionary.txt') as passFile:
        for line in passFile:
            password = line.strip('\n')
            guess = extractFile(zFile, password)
            if guess:
            #do whatever u like here if the password is successful
```

Comment: Don't use `readlines()` just to get an iterable from the file—it's _already_ an iterable. (In fact, [almost _never_ use `readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).) Also, you're leaking the `passFile`, which the OP's original code wasn't; use a `with`.

Comment: noted; and thanks! I assumed the OP would take care of clean up with the snippet.